# "Invalid email: Email (line 24, file "Code")" when trying to send out a mass email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help, I have no coding experience and I want to send out a mass email but it keeps saying Invalid email: Email (line 24, file "Code") when I try running the function.

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
 function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1718; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // First column
    var message = 'Hello, '+ name + row[2]; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[4]; // Third column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Wanting To Represent Your School';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is in line...
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
At least that's what it's saying.

My goal with this code is to send a message to a bunch of colleges asking for merch in which I have a Google Sheet with the first column being the name of the school, the second being the email of the school and the third being the message to the school. I ran the function once and it sent the emails to two schools because I forgot to change the number of rows to process but now I do not want to run again. Please help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Which function? Which code?

Comment: function sendEmails2, I just posted the code. I added more of a description to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=2;
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row=data[i];
    var name=row[0];//Column 1
    var emailAddress=row[1]; //Column 2
    var message='Hello, '+ name + row[2]; // Second column
    var emailSent=row[2];//Column 3
    if (emailSent !== "EMAIL_SENT") { 
      var subject = 'Wanting To Represent Your School';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not it says "Invalid email: Email (line 15, file "Code")"

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1enpePg0dNu1jApZIsXqHrd8__jXsl7IxHKGLzxoOJYg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your startRow should have been 2

Comment: Your numRows was incorrect as well.  Try the current version.  It uses `getLastRow()-1`

Comment: I'm not too sure what that means, can you write it out please?

Comment: It's in the current answer.  [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())